# Struts redirection problem

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts

```
<action-mappings>
    <action input="/welcomeStruts.jsp" name="CheckForm" path="/checkAction" scope="request" type="CheckAction" validate="false">
        <forward name="success" path="/success.jsp" redirect="true"/>
    </action>
    <action path="/Login" forward="/login.jsp"/>
</action-mappings>
```

The action CheckAction doesn't redirect to success.jsp even when I fire

```
return mapping.findForward("success.jsp");
```

Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
return mapping.findForward("success");
```